# JsDoc to PDF renderer

Tags: pdf, jsdoc

Does anyone know a tool to convert JsDoc to PDF ? Or you have to do that trough convert HTML files into PDF ? Thanks for answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSDoc converters I'm aware of are written in JavaScript and are hard-coded to produce HTML tags.

The best HTML->PDF converter I'm aware of is [WKHTMLToPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).  It uses web kit to render the PDF, along with QT's PDF library by the look of it.

So it need some sort of *NIX environment to run.

There are quite a few others floating about, some apps, some services.  You can search the questions here for a more complete list.