# Can JS Doc generate PDF

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am using JS Doc version 3 (https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc). When I run the tool, by default it generates documentation in HTML format. Is it possible to generate doc in PDF format?

Comment: After you have your HTML run them through [http://wkhtmltopdf.org/](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

Comment: This is the solution proposed by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014280/jsdoc-to-pdf-renderer

Comment: No, not on it's own. Like @ZoltanToth suggested, use wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you look at [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html). It is pretty cool and easy to use.

The code you download from the mentioned side contains reach examples.

> What is jsPDF: A HTML5 client-side solution for generating PDFs. Perfect for event tickets, reports, certificates, you name it!

For example to generate pdf of html, just write following code.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

// We'll make our own renderer to skip this editor
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer){
        return true;
    }
};

// All units are in the set measurement for the document
// This can be changed to "pt" (points), "mm" (Default), "cm", "in"
doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170, 
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

This is a snapshot of the sample page jsPDF that you get in your download. It contains different example types, codes and pdf generation example.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Currently there is no tool for converting jsdoc directly to PDF, but you can convert it to some intermediate format (markdown in this example), and then convert it to PDF:

1. Install required tools

   ```
   $ npm install -g markdown-pdf
   $ npm install -g jsdoc-to-markdown
   ```
2. Generate single markdown file with documentation

   ```
   $ jsdoc2md path/to/your/code/** > docs.md
   ```
3. Convert markdown file to PDF:

   ```
   $ markdown-pdf docs.md
   ```

You can change how documentation looks using css stylesheets ([here you can find an example stylesheet](https://github.com/adamburmister/gitprint.com/blob/master/public/css/print.css)).

Answer (score 0):

you got html files now, there are so many tools to convert html to pdf
(i assume you use node.js)

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdf